# SQL Server And Setup File Create...?

Tags: sql-server, installation

01). I have application (Language VB.NET 2008) and I used a database too. and now I want to create a setup file and I have dotnet framework. Now I wanna create a setup like when setup wizard running must install frame work and my application both. Pls tell me how to do it...

02). I used SQL 2000 for database management so now how can I install SQL sever to other PCs ?
Is there an any option to install SQL server like VB.net framework...? I mean we do not need to install VB.net language to run this application. Its enough to install framework . like that can we install something to run SQL server...?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Its really not the same thing. Your application is pre-compiled, and the .net framework just interpretes it. And thats all you need to run the application. However, you have to decide if you want to the DB to remain locally with the application, or it needs to be centralized. i.e., when you install the application on each of the machines, will each install instance have data that is specific to that instance? If so, you will need to package a local DB with your application. Or the other option is to have the a centralized DB (that you host) that your application connects to. So every installation will connect to one DB to get whatever data it needs to.